# How can I launch an on screen keyboard, without a physical keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, accessibility, on-screen-keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 on a desktop, and do not have a keyboard that I can use with it. I would like to install sshd (secure shell daemon) so that I can access that computer, but I can't seem to get onBoard, the on screen, accessibility keyboard to launch. I am sure that it could be launched by typing `onboard' into the terminal, but clearly, I can't do that.

I have tried enabling it through System->Preferences->Assistive Technologies, by indicating `Enable assistive technologies', selecting onBoard as my preferred Mobility application, and then rebooting, to no avail.

Does anyone know of a way to either:

(1) launch the on screen keyboard, using only the mouse, or

(2) install sshd, through a package downloaded on this computer and transferred with a USB drive (remember, I cannot enter my password to gain root privileges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to launch the on screen keyboard by creating a text file on a USB drive with the contents "onboard\n", copying that text from the file to the terminal and continuing from there. I would recommend to anyone with this problem in the future to compose the shell script,

`#!/bin/bash`

onboard

and to execute it from nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and im not using your distro, but if you do want to use the built-in on screen keyboard (part of the accessibility you could try this (thinking also there should be an easier way)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

OSK_CONF_PATH="/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/applications/screen-keyboard-enabled"
if $(dconf read "${OSK_CONF_PATH}"); then
    dconf write "${OSK_CONF_PATH}" false
else
    dconf write "${OSK_CONF_PATH}" true
fi
```

I also bound that commmand to a key

Tested on fc31 under X